# Jenkins: how to set default JDK for all Piplines

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

we have configured a couple JDKs in our Jenkins, which are: JDK8, JDK9, JDK11 etc. The Jenkins itself is running under JDK8. Now, we want to get Jenkins to use JDK9 in all Pipelins, if the "tools" statement isn't in pipeline's definition. Is there a way to do that?

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

Defining a JAVA_HOME environment variable in the Jenkins environment will be enough:

```
export JAVA_HOME = /path/to/JDK9
```

if you run Jenkins in a container, just define JAVA_HOME in the docker run command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /path/to/JDK9:/internal/path/to/JDK9 --env JAVA_HOME=/internal/path/to/JDK9 jenkins:jenkins
```